# flexbox with expandable children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the this layout (`starting layout`). The boxes inside are expandable in height (description text). If a box is expanded, the row should not be affected only the column. I'm using the `bootstrap`grid.

Also the inner boxes are filterable and responsive so they cant be wrapped in a single column.

is this even possible?

Current behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/kunji/t91xppcx/
The problem is that the boxes in the same row also grow in height.

**starting layout:**

```
+-------------------+
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |
| |   | |   | |   | |
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |
| |   | |   | |   | |
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |
+-------------------+
```

**desired layout:**

```
+-------------------+
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |
| |   | |   | |   | |
| |   | +---+ +---+ |
| |   | +---+ +---+ |
| +---+ |   | |   | |
| +---+ +---+ +---+ |
| |   |             |
| +---+             |
+-------------------+
```

**html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should take a look to css grid (display:grid).

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way I see is too divide it into the number of columns first that you would like to display on your page or container, then it won't affect the entire row (of multiple table cells and columns) when you want to expand the row in one single column. You then can use `flex` inside of each column to lay it out however you want, but you can probably easily manage it with just bootstrap grid in this case.
For a more dynamic webpage, you can add *bootstrap* class `col-xs-12 col-sm-4` with Jquery depends on the number of columns you want to have, and use the same idea to divide the articles into the number of columns that you want.

```js
var $clickme = $('.clickme'),
    $box = $('.box');

$box.hide();

$clickme.click( function(e) {
    $(this).text(($(this).text() === 'Hide' ? 'Show' : 'Hide')).next('.box').slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.yellow{
  background: yellow
}
.pink{
  background: pink
}
.grey{
  background: grey
}
.article{
  background: tomato;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.article img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 yellow">
        <div class="article">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="article">
          2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pink">
        <div class="article">
           <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300/?random"/>
           <p>3</p>
           <a href="#" class="clickme content">More</a>
           <p class="box content">
             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="article">
          4
        </div>
        <div class="article">
          5
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 grey">
        <div class="article">
          6
        </div>
        <div class="article">
           <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/290/?random"/>
           <p>7</p>
           <a href="#" class="clickme content">More</a>
           <p class="box content">
             Lorem Ipsum
          </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Please don't just blurt out markup!

Comment: @Rob sorry, I was in a hurry, but I added some text

Comment: I updated the codes with images and text inside the `.article` class to make it more clear with the use of `flex`. Hope it helps a little!

Comment: The problem on my side is that the inner boxes (`.article`) are filterable and responsive. So i cannot have them in single columns.